# how to iterate over specific indexes and check values in javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following model in my angular app:

```
members = [
            {
                id: 'member1',
                name: '',
                instrument1: '',
                instrument2: ''
            },...
            ]
```

I would like to generate a filtered array that can be accessed with an ng-repeat.  the filtered array would contain indexes for all instruments that have values not equal to "" or null.  really the contents of the array are not important for the immediate term, it could just be [0,1,2....].

Comment: You should edit your answer to provide more information and precise that you'd like to obtain a filtered array of elements you can use in an `ng-repeat`. Right now it's not super clear whether you want to count the items that match a precise condition or you want to put them into a separate array...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you filter the members and get the length:

```
function hasAnInstrument(member) {
  // return true if you want to count the member, for instance:
  return !!member.instrument1 || !!member.instrument2;
}

var counter = members.filter(hasAnInstrument).length;
```

Comment: would the argument be 'member'?  how does your approach iterate over every object in the array?  is the function nested in a for loop or other?  I like the simplicity of your approach

Comment: The magic is done by the filter function. It calls the passed function argument for each element of the array. It returns a new array containing all elements for which the function returned true. See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter

Comment: so, ultimately i would like to implement hasAnInstrument in an ng-repeat ("members in hasAnInstrument()"), so it would need to return an array like [0,1,2,3,4]...actually, i guess you could just leave out .length and you're good.  but the structure of your solution would change, right?

Comment: members.filter(hasAnInstrument) gives you exactly the array you are looking for. The structure does not change.

Comment: the only desired change to return true for all instruments, not just for the member....is there a way to do that with a return?  thank you for your help!

Comment: @ernestson I don't understand what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: right now hasAnInstrument returns "true".  I need it to return two "true"s (if they are).  I need to count the instruments, not just the members with instruments....

Comment: I just saw that @LoremIpsum has given you the answer I was about to give, i.e. using .map() to turn the members into ints representing the number of instruments and subsequently using .reduce() to sum up. You might want to have a look at this article explaining map filter and reduce: http://matthewodette.com/map-filter-and-fold-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER**

```
var a = [
  {instrument1: true, instrument2: false},
  {instrument1: false, instrument2: false},
  {instrument1: true, instrument2: true}
];

var count = a.map(function(m) {
  return +!!m.instrument1 + +!!m.instrument2
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b
}, 0);

console.log(count);
```

The `map` transforms each element into 0, 1 or 2 regarding of the properties converted into Booleans, and the reduce simply adds the individual counters together.

**Notes**

- `!!something` converts `something` into a Boolean. `+something` converts `something` into a Number, and `true` is converted into `1` while `false` is converted into `0`. Pretty convenient.
- This code relies on the fact that empty strings or `null`, when converted to a Boolean, equal `false`. This is a pretty weak thing to rely on for models, and in a production/enterprise environment, I'd suggest to make this more explicit by adding a step where the data gets sanitized.
- The code above is so concise it's almost obfuscated. In a production/enterprise environment, I'd suggest loosen it a little bit so it's more explicit.

Comment: this is actually really close, but i need to return two "true"s if !!member.instrument1 && !!member.instrument2...i.e. I need to count all instruments

Comment: i can follow this.  i'm just missing how to put it all together in my controller.  right now in my template i have an `ng-repeat='member in getMembersWithInstruments(members)`.  how would i wrap your solution in that function? thank you, this is really my first excursion into angular and js.  i appreciate your time and willingness to explain.